# Processing does not show up in webpage

Tags: html, processing.js

I have a processing program which I want to display on a browser in an html file. I found an instruction on https://cs.nyu.edu/~kapp/cs101/processing_on_the_web/. It still does not show up in my webpage. I also tried it with the same code from the instruction and it still does not show up. I am using chrome and my html code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bitmap?</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="processing.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Text</h1>
/* @pjs preload="Karte_schweiz_zentriert.jpg","bitmap_zentriert.jpg"; */
<canvas data-processing-sources="bitmap_map_comparison.pde"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

I have the .html file, processing.js, the two .jpg pictures and the bitmap_map_comparison.pde processing code in one folder called bitmap_map_comparison. 
Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: Processing.js was discontinued in December 2018, with the last version before being discontinued being [1.6.6](https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js/tree/v1.6.6). Don't start new projects with it. Please have a look at http://p5js.org instead. It is not API-compatible with Processing 3 (but then, neither was Processing.js, which is _why_ I discontinued it), but does give a solid API to redo most simple sketches.

Comment: Can I just replace the prossening.js file with p5.js? I am new to this.

Comment: very much not, no. Processing.js was an attempt to make Processing's `pde` files "just work" in the browser, whereas p5js is "what you get if you were to make a new technology for the web based on the idea of Processing", so it works rather well, but requires you to rewrite your sketch in terms of [its API instead](https://p5js.org/reference/). Thankfully, there are  [loads of examples](https://p5js.org/examples/) to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `src` incorrectly. Unless you have ProcessingJS in the exact same folder as the program, it will not import as it does not exist. Use this instead:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/processing.js/1.6.6/processing.min.js"></script>
```

Edit: I'm just now realizing that I'm 3 years late and this probably won't help anyone.